# Fill polygon by heat map

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, shapefile

I need to fill my polygon using a heatmap. For source of polygon I've use `shapefile`. 
This is my code:

```
import shapefile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.cm as mcm
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import pylab as plb   


fig     = plt.figure()
ax      = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_frame_on(False)

sf = shapefile.Reader("./data/boundary-polygon")
recs    = sf.records()
shapes  = sf.shapes()
print shapes[1].__dict__
Nshp    = len(shapes)
cns     = []
for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    cns.append(recs[nshp][1])
cns = np.array(cns)
cm    = mcm.get_cmap('Dark2')
cccol = cm(1.*np.arange(Nshp)/Nshp)
#   facecolor=cccol[nshp,:],

for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    ptchs   = []
    pts     = np.array(shapes[nshp].points)
    prt     = shapes[nshp].parts
    par     = list(prt) + [pts.shape[0]]
    for pij in xrange(len(prt)):
        ptchs.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]], alpha=1))
    ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(ptchs,facecolors=((1, 1, 1, 1),),alpha=0.1 ,linewidths=1))
ax.set_xlim(54,67)
ax.set_ylim(50,57)
```

I want to change `facecolors=((1, 1, 1, 1),)` to `facecolors=<image_of_my_heat_map>`. Any help regarding this would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: as a side note, You will get better answers if you code is easier to read.  I think your problem could be reduced down to < 10 LOC and be feed random data so anyone could copy/paste it to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the polygons to be whatever color you want them to be:

```
ptchs=[]
for pij in xrange(len(prt)):
    ptchs.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]], alpha=1, color=your_color))
```

and then create the `PatchCollection` with the warg `match_orginal`:

```
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(ptchs, match_orginal=True, alpha=0.1 ,linewidths=1))
```

Also see [Why is matplotlib.PatchCollection messing with color of the patches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492241/why-is-matplotlib-patchcollection-messing-with-color-of-the-patches/14493391#14493391)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the shapefile API for reading the vector data/polygons. I typically use [OGR](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-module.html) to read GIS vector data. The colour per polygon can be stored as an attribute per feature or just as a scalar which is assigned a colour using the colourmap as you have done here.